# Mount FAT32 filesystem as /home during installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, home-directory, ubiquity, fat32

Setup in Ubuntu 11.10 installation gives me this message while in advanced partitioning:

"The file system type fat32 cannot be mounted on /home, because it is not a fully-functional Unix file system. Please choose a different file system, such as ext2."

Is there a way to force the use of the fat32 partition so I can share it with Windows, but also using it as home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight improvement over the "shared ntfs data partition" recipe suggested by @bodhi.zazen is to set up `/home` on an ext partition, mount an NTFS partition at, say, `/mount/disk` and then replace directories the user's home folder with symlinks to directories on the NTFS partition.

- /home/username/Documents -> /mnt/disk/my_linux_data/Documents
- /home/username/Music     -> /mnt/disk/my_linux_data/Music

etc. Then, if you make a point not to save files in your home folder directly, the process will be totally transparent.

Comment: okay, this way looks pretty much what i need but, is there a way to not make a separate partition for /home this way?

Comment: Sure, you can just keep it on your root partition - it will be just a directory

Comment: Don't do it. It will lead to nothing but trouble. The files will show up on linux as `executable`, since there is no executable flag on fat filesystems, but you need them, to step into a directory. Sharing text files with Windows CR+LF lineendings is another annoyance.

Comment: @user unknown: thank you for downvoting :) Executable flag on files is a matter of mounting options - you can have files without executable bit and directories with one. CR/LF problem is not solved by any other method of sharing files - is your solution "do not share data between Windows and Linux at all"? Also, plain text files used quite rarely these days anyway, especially on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

No. The problem is that vfat does not support permissions so you can not use it as home.

You are almost certainly better off using a shared ntfs data partition.

Alternately you can install the fs-driver in windows

http://www.fs-driver.org/

It will read ext2/3/4 and you are going to be better off using ext4 for /home.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously no because system can't manage user permissions on FAT32 but... BUT WHAT IF WE MOUNT FAT32 AS /home/THEUSER AND MAKE THE WHOLE FAT32 SYSTEM BELONG TO "THEUSER"??? O_o

o_O O_O O_o X_X -_- X_X -_- o_o

Comment: Hmmm... besides your weird faces, (:p) I guess you have a point. If I'm making this partition as a home (~) folder for a user, why would any other user need to have access to it, besides root, which in the way you proposed, would already have it anyway. I mean, it's the home folder! If there's a folder in the system only a specific user should have access to, this is the place!

Comment: Will not work as not every file in $HOME is owned by the user and not every file/directory has the same permissions. .ssh or .gpg for example to name a few.