# How can I access and edit Ubuntu files from a Windows 7 partition?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, files, partitioning

How can I access and edit ubuntu files from a windows 7 partition? should I start saving my files on windows partition so it becomes more accessible to both partitions or just create a separate partition accessible to both OS's?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Windows isn't supported to read the Ubuntu drive. Windows can't read ext4. You need extra software to make it possible. You can try this: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-read-ext3ext4-linux-partition-from-windows-7.html

Comment: It only allow you to download not reedit the files that is already their therefore taking up space. So would it be wise to just save all my files on windows partition? so it would be accessible by all.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is share files between partitions then I would create a FAT32 partition purely for that purpose. That way you would be able to access the information from both Win7 and Ubuntu. For example if your /home partition in Ubuntu was a separate partition to your /root then you could format it as FAT32 and mount it via fstab. When logged into Win7 you would be able to access and read/write to this partition as normal.

Comment: So basically, all I would have to do is create a FAT32 partition?

Comment: Why FAT32 and not NTFS?

Comment: Sorry if I am so slow but I guess your saying that all I would need to do again is to separate the /home and /root partition, right? I am a bit of a Ubuntu newbie recently learning code so forgive me. I want to give it a try I would like it if you had some step by step instructions.

Comment: Was the question clear @kingmilo

Comment: @JonthueMichel Your question was clear, I have just been busy. Correct, the /root and /home partition would have to be seperate, or a partition of your liking, but in your case it makes sense to use /home. FAT32 is more Linux friendly than NTFS, using FAT32 would be much easier. I will post an answer with links to howto's and people who have requested the same as you.

Comment: @kingmilo okay thank you!!! sorry for bugging you.

Comment: @JonthueMichel Not bugging me at all, it's why I am here :) Just letting you know why I took so long to reply. Did you come right, and do you accept my answer below?

Answer (score 1):

As per the *comments* section have a look at the following URL's that provide exactly what you are trying to do. They offer a few scenarios and options some of which are setting up a FAT32 partition within Linux that can be seen from Windows or using a tool called '**Ext2 Installable File System for Windows**' at this [link](http://www.fs-driver.org/).

The links are as follows:

[Mount FAT32 filesystem as /home during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98314/mount-fat32-filesystem-as-home-during-installation)

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=870325

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1241493

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/), to synchronize the files to a server, and between both operating systems, to be easily accessible from both.

Comment: Hmmm... I sorry if this may be a newbie question but I know that it works when I would be log in to both at the same time but dose that work with me on one partition and the other offline? or it just sync via cloud storage? if it is cloud storage how much space can it hold? I know for cloud storage it is 5 GBs or so.

Comment: It synchronizes via intermediate server, and 5 GBs is what the free account comes with. You can buy additional storage, and/or music streaming, if desired as well.

Comment: So it can sync with my 300 GBs of files?

Comment: If you pay for the space, sure. Depending on your connection, it may take quite some time to upload or download the files though, or may incur charges from your ISP. Ubuntu One should be able to handle it fine though.